# Transformation shifts parallelogram to trapezoid - fairly simple

Tags: calculus, geometry, transformation

We are given the region $D= {\{(x,y) | 1 \leq x-y \leq 2, x \leq 0, y\leq 0\} \subseteq \mathbb R^2}$

I drew this region on a piece of paper, it resembles an infinite parallelogram on the third quadrant. $x \in (-\infty,0]$, $y\in [x-2,x-1]$.

We are given the transformation $v=x-y$, $u=x+y$. We are asked to show that the transformation turned the parallelogram into a trapezoid, confined by $v=1, v=2, u=v,u=-v$

I don't completely understand this.

I understand why $v$ goes from $1$ to $2$.

we were given $1 \leq x-y \leq 2$ and $v=x-y$ and so $1 \leq v \leq 2$. that's easy enough.

I don't understand why the $u$ part is true.

I mean, if $1 \leq x-y \leq 2$, then surely $1+2y \leq x+y = u \leq 2+2y$, so I would assume $1+2y \leq u \leq 2+2y$ but that is not very helpful at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been lied to :-)

"Parallelogram" remains "parallelogram", defined by $1\le v\le 2, u \le -v$.

The original domain is defined by $x\le 0, 1\le x-y\le 2$.

This is immediately translated to $u+v\le 0, 1\le v\le 2$ because $2x=u+v$.

ps. Just to make sure: $u=x+y, v=x-y$.

Comment: i agree with you on the $1 \leq v \leq 2$, but would you explain $u \leq -v$?

Comment: my edit crossed with your question. is is clearer now?

Comment: Yes it is much clearer. $u+v=x-y+x+v=2x$, since we know $x \leq 0$, then $2x \leq 0$ as well, which implies $u+v \leq 0$, which implies $u$ is bound by $-v$ But what is the other bound for $u$? $-\infty$?

Comment: Yes, the bound is infinite if there is no finite one.

Comment: Wait, but can't we use the same logic to say $u-v = x-y-x-y=-2y \geq 0$ so $u-v \geq 0$, and then $u \geq v$?

Comment: $u-v=2y$. While, indeed, we know that $y\le -1$, this does not add information.

Comment: No. $u=x-y$, $v=x+y$. so $u-v=x-y-x-y=-2y \geq 0$. so it does tell us that $u \geq v$

Comment: you switched $u$ and $v$ in your last comment.

Comment: ....These silly mistakes is why I'm a lousy programmer :P thank you Sds, appreciate your input.